# Match statement using * and % neither returning precise results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search, match

In this ssql query, I am using a `%` in the `AGAINST` clause.

```
            SELECT firstname,lastname,middlename,company_name, 
                    primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
                    personal_address_line2,personal_address_city,facebook_username,
                    twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
                    personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes,personal_address_zipcode,
                    company_address_zipcode,home_phonenumber,company_phonenumber,
                    cell_phonenumber,birthday_day,birthday_year,hash,image_file
             FROM contacts
             WHERE (
                MATCH(
                    firstname,middlename,lastname,
                    primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
                    personal_address_city,company_name,
                    company_address_line1,company_address_city,
                    facebook_username,twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
                    personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes
                )
                AGAINST ('someemail@email.com%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                OR personal_address_zipcode REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR company_address_zipcode REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR home_phonenumber REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR company_phonenumber REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR cell_phonenumber REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR birthday_day REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR birthday_year REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
            ) 
            AND addressbook_id = 4
```

In this ssql query, I am using a `*` in the `AGAINST` clause.

```
            SELECT firstname,lastname,middlename,company_name, 
                    primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
                    personal_address_line2,personal_address_city,facebook_username,
                    twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
                    personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes,personal_address_zipcode,
                    company_address_zipcode,home_phonenumber,company_phonenumber,
                    cell_phonenumber,birthday_day,birthday_year,hash,image_file
             FROM contacts
             WHERE (
                MATCH(
                    firstname,middlename,lastname,
                    primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
                    personal_address_city,company_name,
                    company_address_line1,company_address_city,
                    facebook_username,twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
                    personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes
                )
                AGAINST ('someemail@email.com*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                OR personal_address_zipcode REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR company_address_zipcode REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR home_phonenumber REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR company_phonenumber REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR cell_phonenumber REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR birthday_day REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
                OR birthday_year REGEXP('(someemail@email.com*)') 
            ) 
            AND addressbook_id = 4
```

Neither are returning just where the content precisely equals atleast `someemail@email.com`. It's returning back everything with com or email or some. What changes do I need to make? There is a `FULLTEXT` index on the match columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be to put the address in quotes and don't use a wildcard at all:

```
AGAINST ('"someemail@email.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Like that.

And I don't think you need the boolean mode for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your fulltext search is not working because `@` and `.` (and in fact most non-alphanumeric characters) are word delimiters. Therefore 1. e-mails get indexed as three separate words and 2. word delimiters are ignored from your search string.

Just create a regular multi-columns index on your columns, and search with a standard `LIKE`:

```
WHERE firstname LIKE 'someemail@email.com%' OR ...
```

This query will be able to use the index and the search will be very efficient.

Also, get rid of these `REGEXP()`. They are useless (redundant) and will kill your performances (no index can be used).